# My script is not working for looping through 5 images only once

Tags: javascript, image, loops

I need to loop through few images (here 5) only once. Each image should be presented for 20 seconds and then move on to the other OR by participants clicking on the image!
However, this scipr doesnt seem to work. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
<html>
       <head>
          <title>Practice1</title>

          <script type="text/javascript">

                      function displayNextImage() {
                        for(var x=0; x<images.length; x++){
                          document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
                        }
                      }


              function startTimer() {
                  setTimeout(displayNextImage, 20000);
              }

             var images = [], 
              images[0] = "S1b.jpg";
              images[1] = "S2b.jpg";
              images[2] = "S3b.jpg";
              images[3] = "S4b.jpg";
              images[4] = "S5b.jpg";

          </script>


    </body>
                <button onload="startTimer()" onclick="displayNextImage()">
                  <img id="img">
            </button> 


       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Yes, this is what it give me: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement I am not sure why!!!

Comment: What you are doing is setting every image to img src after 20secs, which will show just the last image after 20secs. Of course after fixing your syntax error.

Comment: Do you know how I can loop through the images after each click only once? I am not sure how to change this to get that!

Answer (score 3):

You have invalid syntax right here:

```
var images = [], //HERE!!!!!
          images[0] = "S1b.jpg";
          images[1] = "S2b.jpg";
          images[2] = "S3b.jpg";
          images[3] = "S4b.jpg";
          images[4] = "S5b.jpg";
```

`images[index]` is not a new variable, its an addition to the array, so replace that comma with a semi-colon:

```
var images = [];
          images[0] = "S1b.jpg";
          images[1] = "S2b.jpg";
          images[2] = "S3b.jpg";
          images[3] = "S4b.jpg";
          images[4] = "S5b.jpg";
```

Now, your script is going to loop this array and assign the source of the image extremely fast..you probably won't even notice it cycle, FYI